# Posting Link on Facebook - site description

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, share, facebook-opengraph

I have already included these tags in my html file:

> ```
>   <head> <meta property="og:title" content="MyTitle"/> 
>   <meta property="og:site_name" content="MySite"/>        
>   <meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com"/> 
>   <meta property="og:description" content="description ..."/>
> ```

But if someone copies the Url to Facebook and shares it, it just shows a secton of the page as its description.

Any idea, what could be wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook caches some OG data, hence it might take some time for it to update. Try hosting the file in a different folder and see if it's still happening.

Answer (score 2):

As [MMM](/users/986618/mmm) mentioned, Facebook does indeed cache the OpenGraph metadata.

It sounds like you want to use the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) (sometimes still referred to as the Linter) — for two reasons.

1. It will confirm to you what it is that Facebook's crawler can see, so you can tell whether or not you have implemented the OG metadata correctly; but also
2. It will reset Facebook's cache  of your OG metadata, which sounds like you also want to do.

So take a look at the Debugger and that may well resolve your problems. Good luck!